# Restrict a particular user to access the particular webpage

Tags: php

I want to restrict users to access particular webpages in my applicatipn. In my application I have 4 webpages like Mumbai, Delhi, Bangalore, Kolkata and I have havie 4 users say User1, User2, User3 and User4. All users are Admin.

My requirement is that all 4 user can't access Mumbai page, 
User1 can access only Delhi page, 
User2 and User3 can access only Bangalore page and 
User4 can access only Kolkata page.

I Used following Code for Delhi Page:

```
$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) {
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       
}
```

But it won't work

Comment: So does $login_session['login_user'] have the usernames as values or some other information?

Comment: $login_session['login_user'] has usernames as value

Comment: why do not you store permissions in a table like you can store userid and pageid in this table. If user needs to be given access to a page, then make an entry in this table.

Comment: This work for me.$login_session['login_user'] = 'User22';
            $allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) {
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
   exit();       
}

Comment: @user2636930 if $login_session['login_user'] does not exist in $allowed_users array then nothing to do with this code .this code is fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
if(isset($login_session['login_user']))
{
    $login = $login_session['login_user'];
  if (!in_array($login, $allowed_users)) {
     Header( "HTTP/1.1 403 Restricted Content" );  
  }
}else{
  Header( "HTTP/1.1 403 Restricted Content" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really does work for me. Maybe you need to dump the login_session array and the allowed array.

This code perfectly does your job:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'User1';
$login_session = array(
    'id'            =>  session_id(),
    'login_user'    =>  $_SESSION['username']
);
var_dump($login_session['login_user']); // User1
$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
var_dump(in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)); // bool False
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) { //Check if the logged user is not in this array (False)
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=include1.php">'; // Printed and redirected
   exit();       
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
I want to give access for Delhi Page to User1 & User2,user3,User4 Dont access delhi Page i used code which suggested but it won't work
please help me

I store session value as follows
<?php
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from yulogin where username='$user_check' ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
$login_session=$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>

Comment: You have to set proper $allowed_users on each page

Comment: Sorry But i Din't get you,
My User Names are Shaba, Mubarak,Gururaj &Diganta
Shaba Having Access Only Delhi page & Noth Others
Gururaj & Mubarak Having Access Only Bangalor page & not others
Diganta Having Access Kolkata Page & not others 
Then How can i impliment this in code which you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working please check value in your session variable or you can try in another way

```
$dis_allowed_users = array('User5','User6','User6');
if (in_array($login_session['login_user'], $dis_allowed_users))
{
    echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=Admin-Dashboard.php">';
    exit();       
}
```

Comment: please check you session variable

Comment: please tell the value in your session variable

Comment: I stored username in session User are Shaba,Gururaj,Diganta,Mubarak
User Shaba having only Delhi Page access
User Gururaj & Mubarak having Only Bangalore Page Access
User Diganta having only Kokata Page access

Comment: i suggest that you add new field in your user table and add allowed page with comma separate, and after login get page from user name and then call in_array function. i think it should help

Comment: I try for this also
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'User1';
$login_session = array(
    'id'            =>  session_id(),
    'login_user'    =>  $_SESSION['username']
);
var_dump($login_session['login_user']);
$allowed_users = array('User2','User3','User4');
var_dump(in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users));
if (!in_array($login_session['login_user'], $allowed_users)) { //Check if the logged user is not in this array (False)
   echo "You dont have permission to access this page";
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=include1.php">'; 
   exit();

Comment: well, but whn i log in with user2 then user2 also access delhi page which access by only user1